# CSS pseudo-selector to select the current element within querySelector?

Tags: javascript, css

What's the CSS pseudo-selector to select an element's self?

For example, this does not work:

```
Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.program_record_outer'), programBox => {
    return programBox.querySelector('> div')
});
```

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Element': '> div' is not a valid selector.

But I believe something like this would:

```
Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.program_record_outer'), programBox => {
    return programBox.querySelector(':self > div')
});
```

However, `:self` isn't a thing, and `:root` refers to the document root, so how do I refer to the current context?

Comment: Are you looking for `this`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox `:this` is not a valid pseudo-selector either.

Comment: If you're looking for the immediate children why not use `programBox.children` and filter by `nodeType`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm not looking for immediate children. I'm looking for a descendant of an immediate child with specific constraints.

Comment: Late for the party but I think [`matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) will help. For your specific case, [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) too, though it's not widely supported.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In some of the latest browsers ([Chrome, Firefox 32+, Opera 15+, and Safari 7.0+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope#compat-desktop)) you can use the [`:scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope) selector in calls to `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`:

```js
let result = [...document.querySelectorAll('.program_record_outer')].map(
  programBox => programBox.querySelector(':scope > div')
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<div class="program_record_outer">
  <div>1</div>
</div>
<div class="program_record_outer">
  <div>2</div>
</div>
<div class="program_record_outer">
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Scope! That's it. I knew there was a thing, but I couldn't think of it and Google didn't turn up anything. Will accept in ~10 minutes.

Comment: But why use `querySelector` when the DOM API will do?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Just a reminder that this may be a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of OP's full use case. Regardless, I think `:scope` is a good thing to know and can be useful in certain contexts.

Comment: yeah this works just beware, it's experimental, and browsers haven't really adopted it yet:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope

Comment: Correct. The inner selector will be more complicated than simply `:scope > div`.

Comment: `:scope` is getting removed, any suggestions for alternatives?

Comment: @EmilMoe From what I can tell, `:scope` in the latest DOM is only getting removed within stylesheets, not calls to `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll`

Comment: thanks @gyre - it's too useful in `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` but has no use case in CSS, so they are making the right call. Do you have a link where this decision is confirmed?

Comment: @brennanyoung Hi Brennan, sorry this is such a late reply, but if you look at the latest Selectors Level 4 draft (https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-scope-pseudo) it still contains :scope, and hence is not to my knowledge deprecated. There is presently no useful way to use it in stylesheets, but that may change in the future.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work for the sibling operator `:scope + div` or `:scope ~ div`

Comment: This also doesn't work if all you want is the "current element". For example, `document.body.querySelector(':scope')` returns null instead of the body node :(

Comment: @Christian This is an interesting side effect, but also why would you do that?  it's equivalent to the less convoluted `document.body`.

Comment: @MicahHenning because in my (and the OP's) case, the current dom node was variable (not just `document.body`).

Answer (score -2):

Another option (which I haven't seen mentioned) is to use `*`, e.g. `* > div`.