# querySelectorAll to include self

Tags: javascript

```html
<div class="a">
    <span class="a">a</span>
    <span class="a">b</span>
    <span class="a">c</span>
</div>
```

Assuming I have a variable called `divA` representing the top level div node. `divA.querySelectorAll('.a')` will return a list of the 3 `span.a`s. I wonder if there's an easy way to return a list of 4 elements including the divA itself?

I know I could start from a higher level node, but let's assume there might be other `.a` elements that I don't want to mess with them.

In reality I still need to test whether `divA` matches my selector or not. So is there a way for css selector to test an element itself?

I could create a parent node and run querySelectorAll from there. But if there's an easier way, I don't need to go that far.

Comment: `[divA, ...divA.querySelectorAll('.a')]`

Comment: I mean, just add it to an array? `[divA, ...divA.querySelectorAll('.a')]`

Comment: Thank you so much. In reality I still need to test whether divA matches my selector or not. Is there a way for css selector to test an element itself?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I still need to test whether divA matches my selector or not. Is there
>   a way for css selector to test an element itself?

`querySelector()` cannot return the context element it's running on.

What you can do is use @Andreas' solution followed by a `filter()`/`matches()` combo.

```
[divA, ...divA.querySelectorAll('.a')].filter(el => el.matches('.a'));
```

Comment: Good solution. However, I personally think that `divA.matches('.a') && divA || divA.querySelector('.a')` is a more elegant (and technically less exhaustive) solution for this issue. See [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60831454/4174789).

Comment: @BartHofland agreed (of course :) but this question is about `.querySelectorAll()` so it's messier.

Comment: Oh... Yes, indeed. I didn't notice. Sorry.

Comment: One could still do `[...divA.matches('.a') ? [divA] : [], ...divA.querySelectorAll('.a')]` that is even uglier, but probably still more efficient for larger sets of elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for I guess: `:scope`

EDIT:
Just like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43354126/14034888

```
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

console.log(parent.querySelectorAll(':scope .box'));
```

should return (if it exists in the DOM of course) a NodeList of length 5 with `.parent` as the first element in the list and the children (and grand children) filling the remaining four indices...

```
<div class='parent box'>
   <div class='box'></div>
   <div class='box'>
     <div class='inner box'></div>
   </div>
   <div class='box'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That anchors the search to the current element and is thus used to stipulate only direct children of it. However, it cannot be used to *return* the context element itself.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Alright, @Ivan.  I edited my answer. Thank you. 