# How to have element.querySelector() include the root element?

Tags: javascript

I'm in a unique situation where I need `element.querySelector(selector)` to test against the root `element` itself, and return it if it matches.

How would you do this?

Note that `element.parentNode.querySelector(selector)` wouldn't work for me since it would amtch against `element`'s siblings.

Comment: @Teemu `.closest()` goes *up*.

Comment: @Teemu but if `.querySelector()` *does* find a match, then from that point `.closest()` will I think return that found element itself, if `.closest()` in the DOM API works like jQuery's.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do

```
let matched = element.matches(selector) && element || element.querySelector(selector);
```

Tests the element first, which probably would make sense given the behavior of `.querySelector()`.

Comment: Lovely. Didn't know about `matches`.

Comment: I think this answer is more elegant than the accepted answer to the question that is referred to (since this question is being marked as a duplicate).

Comment: @BartHofland absolutely. For what it's worth, if Pointy adds this answer over there as well, I'll upvote it. Just ping me please : )

Comment: @DanielBirowskyPopeski well the thing about the linked duplicate is that it involves `.querySelectorAll()`, so it'd be a little messier.