# Trouble accessing nested child element using querySelector in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm encountering an issue with the querySelector method in JavaScript, specifically when attempting to access nested child elements. I have a selected element, and my goal is to retrieve the first child of the selected element and then obtain the first child of that inner element.

I've tried the following code:

```js
let selected = document.querySelector(".main-box")
var desiredElement = selected.querySelector("div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)");
```

However, this seems to produce the same result as:

```js
var desiredElement = selected.querySelector("div:nth-child(1)");
```

It appears that the second part of the selector (> div:nth-child(1)) is not behaving as expected.

My HTML structure is as follows:

```html
<div class="main-box">
    <div>
        <div>Target Element</div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but it works fine when I use this code

```js
var desiredElement = document.querySelector(".main-box > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)")
```

then why this code is not working

```js
let selected = document.querySelector(".main-box")
var desiredElement = selected.querySelector("div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)");
```

Answer (score 1):

The second part is supposedly to be your div with the inner text Target Element. The selection has to be a bit different because the `:nth-child()` selector selects child elements according to their position among all the sibling elements within a parent element.

I already have tried this approach:

```
var desiredElement = selected.querySelector("div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)");
```

but it doesn't give the desired effect as you want.

To my knowledge it probably has to do with the `:nth-child()` CSS pseudo-class which in this case doesn't match with the index of the element in the child list of the parent.

In other words, the div which you are trying to get through the querySelector here is probably wrong: `var desiredElement = selected.querySelector("div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)");`

This approach is way more concise when you are dealing with children of other DOM elements.

```js
var selected = document.querySelector(".main-box");
var desiredElement2 = document.querySelector(".main-box :nth-child(1)");
var desiredElement3 = document.querySelector(".main-box :nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)");

console.log(selected);


console.log(desiredElement2);

console.log(desiredElement3);
```

```html
<div class="main-box">
    <div>
        <div>Target Element</div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: then why this code works fine for extracting first div child of 2nd child of selected elem :-

`var anotherElement = selected.querySelector("div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1)");`

Comment: Because there aren't 2 `div`s with `class="main-box"`?

Answer (score 1):

The [`baseElement.querySelector(selectors)` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) returns

> The first descendant element of `baseElement` which matches the
> specified group of `selectors`. **The entire hierarchy of elements is
> considered when matching**, including those outside the set of elements
> including `baseElement` and its descendants; in other words, `selectors`
> is first applied to the whole document, not the `baseElement`, to
> generate an initial list of potential elements. The resulting elements
> are then examined to see if they are descendants of `baseElement`. The
> first match of those remaining elements is returned by the
> `querySelector()` method.

Since your `div.main-box` is a `div:nth-child(1)` itself, selecting the first element within it that also matches `div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)` will get the `div.main-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)`.

To get the desired result, you can instead use

- ```
  document.querySelector(".main-box > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)")
  ```
- ```
  document.querySelector(".main-box")?.querySelector(":scope > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)")
  ```
- ```
  document.querySelector(".main-box")?.firstElementChild?.firstElementChild
  ```
- ```
  document.querySelector(".main-box")?.querySelector("div:nth-child(1)")?.querySelector("div:nth-child(1)")
  ```

Comment: Specifically the [The entire hierarchy counts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector#the_entire_hierarchy_counts) section helps explain this.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a selected element, and my goal is to retrieve the first child of the selected element and then obtain the first child of that inner element.

In this instance, the easiest amendment you can make to your selector is to add a `:not(.main-box)` function to indicate that you *don't* want the selector to start counting from `.main-box`:

```
div:nth-child(1):not(.main-box) > div:nth-child(1)
```

---

*Working Example:*

```js
let selected = document.querySelector('.main-box');
let desiredElement = selected.querySelector('div:nth-child(1):not(.main-box) > div:nth-child(1)');
desiredElement.classList.add('desiredElement');
```

```css
div > div > div {
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

.desiredElement {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-box">
    <div>
        <div>Target Element 1-1</div>
        <div>Element 1-2</div>
        <div>Element 1-3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Element 2-1</div>
        <div>Element 2-2</div>
        <div>Element 2-3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
         <div>Element 3-1</div>
         <div>Element 3-2</div>
         <div>Element 3-3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or use `:scope > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)` (See [CSS pseudo-selector to select the current element within querySelector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43354070/215552))

Comment: You can simplify it further with `:scope div div`.

Comment: thanks @HereticMonkey  this code `:scope > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)` 
works as expected and fulfills my needs, because i am using for loop to accessing specific child element based on the same selector inside for loop.